# How to select to make v-textfield read-only?

Tags: vuetify.js

for my model, I use a v-select and a v-text field for when a selected value makes v-textfield read-only, but how is this implemented in vuetify?

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="3" md="3">
        <v-select
          :items="['Yes','No']"         
          label="select"         
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>      

      <v-col cols="12" sm="3" md="3">
        <v-text-field         
          label="ReadOnly"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the selected value of the `v-select`, then control the `readonly` prop of the v-select based on the selected value. I assume that when you selected "yes", the textfield will be readonly

```html
<v-select
  v-model="selected"
  :items="['Yes','No']"         
  label="select"         
></v-select>
...
<v-text-field         
  label="ReadOnly"
  :readonly="selected === 'yes'"
></v-text-field>
```

Here's a sample [demo at codesandbox:](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-liskov-rwoul?file=/src/components/Playground.vue)

[image]